# std::vector doesn't call move constructor with objects with noexcept move constructs

Tags: c++, c++14, copy-constructor, move-semantics, move-constructor

I've been struggeling a lot lately with move and copy constructors and can't seem to find the awnser on my own.
The structure is fairly simple. A class OWUP which holds a std::unique_ptr to an object (in this example an int), a class One which is a simple wrapper around std::vector of OWUP's and class Two which is a simple wrapper std::vector of One's.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class OWUP {
public:
    OWUP()
    : data(nullptr)
    { }

    OWUP(const OWUP &) = delete;
    OWUP &operator=(const OWUP &) = delete; 
    OWUP(OWUP &&) noexcept = default;
    OWUP &operator=(OWUP &&) noexcept = default; 

    std::unique_ptr<int> data; 
};

class One {
public:
    One(std::size_t numof_datas)
    : datas(numof_datas)
    { }

    One(const One &) = delete;
    One &operator=(const One &) = delete; 
    One(One &&) noexcept = default;
    One &operator=(One &&) noexcept = default; 

    std::vector<OWUP> datas;
};

class Two {
public:
    Two(std::size_t numof_ones, std::size_t num_of_datas)
    : ones(numof_ones, One(num_of_datas))
    { }

    Two(const Two &) = delete;
    Two &operator=(const Two &) = delete; 
    Two(Two &&) noexcept = default;
    Two &operator=(Two &&) noexcept = default;

    std::vector<One> ones;
};
```

The code gets the following error code with `g++ -std=c++14 example.cpp`

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.3.1/memory:64:0,
                 from example.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = One; _Args = {const One&}]':
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:210:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_fill_n<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_fill_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = One*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = One; bool _TrivialValueType = false]'
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:255:17:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_fill_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&) [with _ForwardIterator = One*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = One]'
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:366:39:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_fill_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, const _Tp&, std::allocator<_Tp2>&) [with _ForwardIterator = One*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = One; _Tp2 = One]'
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/stl_vector.h:1337:33:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_fill_initialize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&) [with _Tp = One; _Alloc = std::allocator<One>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = One]'
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/stl_vector.h:298:27:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const value_type&, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = One; _Alloc = std::allocator<One>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = One; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<One>]'
example.cpp:40:39:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'One::One(const One&)'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
example.cpp:29:3: note: declared here
   One(const One &) = delete;
   ^~~
```

I've tried my best to force it to use move constructors. I also tried to create my own move constructors with std::move, but that resulted int the same compile error. I'm aware that std::vector tests for move_if_noexcept(), but for can't find out why it doesn't. What is it that i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the problem is here:

```
Two(std::size_t numof_ones, std::size_t num_of_datas)
: ones(numof_ones, One(num_of_datas))
{ }
```

You can't move from `One` you create here, you really need to copy from it `numof_ones` times.

Comment: Hmm I don't know if i fully understand your awnser, but removing One(num_of_datas) and manually adding the One(num_of_datas) numof_ones number of times in a loop does fix the problem. Is this the fix you meant?

Comment: @73nismit you're calling a constructor of vector that copies the argument. from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) - *2) Constructs the container with count **copies** of elements with value value.*.

Comment: @73nismit moving an object is like moving an apple from a box to another box.  The result is that last box looks like the first before the move; but you didn't need to go to the shops to get more apples.  This works great if you only need 1 apple.  If you need 5 apples in 5 boxes though; you're going to need to get more; in which case you need to copy the box.

Comment: Also, it doesn't say that the move constructor is deleted, it's the copyconstructor that is deleted. switch places on "move" and "copy"?

Comment: @UKmonkey I don't want to copy or move to begin with, i want to initialize the size of the 2d array

Comment: @73nismit I said that because you said you said you didn't get moving Vs copying.  Keeping with the apple analogy; initialising the vector size means you want to say how many boxes to make; your options are to say "make default boxes" which will likely be empty (call the default constructor), or "make boxes that are a copy of this one".  By giving the vector a size and an object, it goes with that you want the latter.  I hope that helps make things clear about moving and copying! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way of constructing a `std::vector<One>` of size `numof_ones` without `One` having a default constructor or a copy constructor. The constructor you chose takes `numof_ones` **copies** of the single value you give it into each element of the vector.

The easiest solution is probably to not initialize `ones` in the constructor initializer list but instead initialize it in the body of the constructor:

```
Two(std::size_t numof_ones, std::size_t num_of_datas) {
    ones.reserve(numof_ones);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != numof_ones; ++i) {
        ones.emplace_back(num_of_datas);
    }
}
```

(Technically you could probably use the `std::vector` constructor that takes two iterators and provide your own custom iterator but it is probably not worth the effort).

Comment: This is what I did to prevent the compiler errors, but I don't think it's the right way to do it though. It doesn't feel right.